# how to set datagridview column is left side of a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have to using a datagridview in my project so need to show datagridview column in left side of datagridview like,

```
             column 1       column 2
-------------------------------------------
column 1 

column 2
```

...

```
`// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'hRPayDataSet.employee' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

 this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.hRPayDataSet.employee);       
 dataGridView1.DataSource =employeeBindingSource;

 DataTable table2 = (DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
 DataTable tTable = null;
 try { tTable = GenerateTransposedTable(table2); }
 catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
 dataGridView1.DataSource = tTable;
 dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = true;
 dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;`
```

please help me....

Comment: Why you need column 1 as column as well as row? are you trying to plot matrix format data to a datagrid?

Comment: yes @ Arul manivannan

Comment: As shown this makes no sense. Maybe you want to rotate/switch rows and columns?

Comment: yes I want to rotate a rows and columns but I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: First bind your `DataGridView` to `DataTable`

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource);
DataTable tTable = null;
try
{
    tTable = GenerateTransposedTable(table);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = tTable;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = true;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```

`GenerateTransposedTable` transposes your `table`:

```
private DataTable GenerateTransposedTable(DataTable inputTable)
{
    DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

    outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

    foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
    {
        string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
        outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
    }

    for (int rCount = 0; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();

        newRow[0] = inputTable.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString();
        for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
        {
            string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
            newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue;
        }
        outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    return outputTable;
}
```

### **Test Code:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("A");
    table.Columns.Add("B");
    table.Columns.Add("C");
    table.Columns.Add("D");
    table.Columns.Add("E");
    table.Columns.Add("F");

    dataGridView2.DataSource = table;

    DataTable table2 = (DataTable)(dataGridView2.DataSource);
    DataTable tTable = null;
    try
    {
        tTable = GenerateTransposedTable(table2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    dataGridView2.DataSource = tTable;
    dataGridView2.RowHeadersVisible = true;
    dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
}
```

### UPDATE 2:

Replace Your code with this:

```
// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'hRPayDataSet.employee' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.hRPayDataSet.employee);
dataGridView1.DataSource = employeeBindingSource;

var bds = (BindingSource)(dataGridView1.DataSource);
HRPayDataSet ds = (HRPayDataSet)bds.DataSource;

DataTable dt = TransposeTable(ds.Tables[0]);
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

new `TransposeTable()` method:

```
private DataTable TransposeTable(DataTable inputTable)
{
    DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        outputTable.Columns.Add("col" + i);
    }

    for (int rCount = 0; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();
        newRow[0] = inputTable.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString();
        for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 2; cCount++)
        {
            string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
            newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue;
        }
        outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    return outputTable;
}
```

Comment: I got exception `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.` on DataTable table = (DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource);

Comment: How you bind your `dataGridView`?

Comment: using a dtagridview properities

Comment: Can you provide me a code when you binding some data to your `dataGridView`.

Comment: Anyway, before that you can try `var dbs = (BindingSource)dataGridView2.DataSource;
            DataTable table = (DataTable)dbs.DataSource;` instead of `DataTable table = (DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource);`

Comment: If you don't mine please tell where you use a `DataTable table = (DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource);
DataTable tTable = null;
try
{
    tTable = GenerateTransposedTable(table);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = tTable;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = true;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;` Because I used in form load

Comment: I use `dataGridView2.DataSource =employeeBindingSource;

    DataTable table2 = (DataTable)(dataGridView2.DataSource);` is actually displayed datatable not transpose table please tell me

Comment: Did you use the last part of code? `DataTable tTable = null;
    try
    {
        tTable = GenerateTransposedTable(table2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    dataGridView2.DataSource = tTable;
    dataGridView2.RowHeadersVisible = true;
    dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;`

Comment: this part executes only by use of table not tTable

Comment: You need `tTable` to call `GenerateTransposedTable(table2)` and get transposed `DataTable` to it, then bind it to your `dataGridView`

Comment: yeah its true I agree but when I use `dataGridView2.DataSource =employeeBindingSource` is insistently showing a values(in original table) not execute `DataTable tTable = null;.................`

Comment: is your `employeeBindingSource ` a `DataTable` ?

Comment: What exactly `table` from `dataset` you want to bind to `datagridview`?

Comment: try to assign `dataGridView2.DataSource = null;` before `dataGridView2.DataSource = tTable;`

Comment: Please clearly understand when I use `dataGridView2.DataSource =employeeBindingSource` is execute and display only old table value is not allow to execute next line of codes. I checked by breakpoint

Comment: please provide your code, so I can test it. (update your question part, because in comments its hard to read)

Comment: I've tested and added new code for you, please check.