# How to rotate datagridview with 90 degree

Tags: c#, datagridview

Original datagrieview:

[image]

What I want is to rotate it with 90 degree:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to rotate a button control in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130008/is-it-possible-to-rotate-a-button-control-in-winforms)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864180/rotating-a-net-panel-in-windows-forms

Comment: Summary: you can't.

Comment: I think you can. Take a look at these 2 questions, combining them you can achieve  your goal. 
1) [how to set datagridview column is left side of a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043869/how-to-set-datagridview-column-is-left-side-of-a-datagridview)

  2) [Vertical text in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782674/vertical-text-in-datagridview)

Comment: How did you get the image in the second form. :)

Comment: or why don't you consider using a wpf form.